# Visual Studio-Community (ERROR 0x80070643, Team Explorer 2015 Failed)

Tags: visual-studio

I was installing Visual Studio-Community 2015, and I got the error (0x80070643), also known as Team Explorer Fails. The installer runs for a while, and then outputs this: [(Screenshot)](http://gyazo.com/b59b2dcb3e13f3b7ad0adaf7cca5ec9c) I have used microsoft repair tools, reinstalled the redistributables, checked the hash, (fine) and run a SFC scan, (fine). I have been searching everywhere, yet I am to have found a solution. Here is the log, (shortened, because it is massive): [(Error Log)](http://pastebin.com/S6dZM6RN)

Comment: Do you have another version of VS installed? I had something like this too and it was because I had VS 2013 and was installing 2015 while I already had 2013, which gave me errors too.

Answer (score 1):

That error code is generic in that it just means "Fatal error during installation"

You need the installation log of the particular MSI that failed.

Do you have that already? Look in your temporary directory (i.e. just type in **%TEMP%** in the windows explorer address bar and hit enter) for something like "dd_vs_*version info*_vs_**teamExplorerCore.log**"

If that's not there, you might be able to manually execute the MSI yourself and capture a log:

From a command prompt (ideally elevated) you could run the command:

```
msiexec /l*v "%TEMP%\teamexplorer.log" /i "*full installer path*packages\TeamExplorer\Core\vs_teamExplorerCore.msi" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" USING_EXUIH="1"
```

You need to update that command so that the path to the MSI is correct. If you've downloaded the ISO, then it will be in there; otherwise, while you're running the installer, you can probably find it under the package cache, e.g. *C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{48992F68-BEE6-35D8-89AC-6A81406F1096}v14.0.24712* looking at the log.

Using a tool like Void Tools Everything will make it easy to find the MSI and logs amongst a sea of temporary folders and caches.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I have already tried this path, didn't unfortunately work, ended up re-installing Windows... :/

Comment: Ouch! Well hopefully you're up and running now :)